# set custom layout to screen height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have to add a layout to the screen height removing action bar height. I am using below code -

```
View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.left_interaction_layout, null);
        double screenSize = 0;
    try {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        int dens = dm.densityDpi;
        double wi = (double) width / (double) dens;
        double hi = (double) height / (double) dens;
        double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
        screenSize = Math.sqrt(x + y);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
        double screenByTwoSize = screenSize / 3;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        // int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        // int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        float mXDpi = metrics.xdpi;
        float mYDpi = metrics.ydpi;
        int screenWidth = (int) Math.round(screenByTwoSize * mXDpi);
        int screenHeight = (int) Math.round(screenByTwoSize * mYDpi);

        popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, screenWidth, 200, true);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        // Get ListView object from xml
        final ListView listView = (ListView) popupView
                .findViewById(R.id.list);
        try {
            popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, 120, screenHeight * 2 + 250,
                    true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        // popup.showAsDropDown(tvcountry);
        Rect location = LoginActivity.locateView(v);
        popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 0,
                location.bottom);
        popup.update();
        popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {

            }
        });
```

I have hardcoded height which may be different for different screen size. How can I achieve that dynamically. I have to make this layout to screen height with removing action bar height so it will work like navigation drawer

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

     int   DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int    DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;`

Answer (score 0):

you can  Calculate ActionBar height as follows

```
  TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

and remove the actionbar height with your actual height